# Maven Wrapper vs Bundle Maven 3

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3

As we can see in the picture for the Maven home path. 
May I know what is the difference between `Maven Wrapper` and `Bundled Maven 3`?

[image]

Comment: The maven wrapper is a package which is part of the project, can be identified by seen things like `mvnw.cmd` and `mvnw` in the root of your project which will automatically download the defined version of Maven. The bundled one is the configiuration of IntelliJ IDEA which has a packaged Apache Maven version with the installation of IntellIJ.